# How do I stop snaps mounting during boot on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-18.04, snap

Booting my very capable PC has become a fingers-on-chalkboard-grating slow nightmare because of snap. It's gone from 5-10 seconds to login screen after GRUB to now 30-45 seconds, sometimes up to a minute or more.

This is **absurd**.

I'd prefer to not remove every single snap on my machine, but I'm prepared to do that. How do I defeat snap mounts on boot and regain my sanity, without having to scorch the earth?

***Specifically looking for an answer to this:*** how do I modify individual snaps so that they do not mount during boot?

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
          8.812s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          6.256s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.042s bolt.service
          3.008s snap-spotify-42.mount
          2.994s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-93.mount
          2.917s snap-discord-115.mount
          2.525s snap-chromium-1399.mount
          2.515s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-100.mount
          2.416s snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount
          2.392s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-550.mount
          2.224s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
          2.214s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1513.mount
          2.174s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount
          2.170s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-748.mount
          2.149s snap-postman-128.mount
          1.953s snap-storage\x2dexplorer-17.mount
          1.946s snap-core18-1885.mount
          1.749s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-db865690\x2db43f\x2d485b\x2d8bab\x2d808735a403a8.service
          1.725s unifi-video.service
          1.632s dev-loop3.device
          1.632s dev-loop2.device
          1.575s dev-loop5.device
          1.557s dev-loop6.device
          1.555s dev-loop7.device
          1.464s dev-loop9.device
          1.452s dev-loop8.device
          1.441s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-570.mount
          1.426s snap-core-10185.mount
          1.409s snap-spotify-43.mount
          1.400s snap-libreoffice-196.mount
          1.384s snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount
          1.380s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount
          1.370s snap-postman-129.mount
          1.214s dev-loop10.device
          1.135s dev-loop11.device
          1.132s dev-loop1.device
          1.089s dev-loop21.device
          1.072s snap-vlc-1620.mount
          1.070s dev-loop19.device
          1.054s dev-loop18.device
          1.041s dev-loop20.device
           981ms dev-loop12.device
           975ms dev-loop14.device
           968ms systemd-logind.service
           944ms dev-loop4.device
           903ms dev-loop13.device
           902ms dev-loop17.device
           901ms dev-loop16.device
           881ms dev-loop22.device
           834ms snap-core18-1932.mount
           809ms snap-chromium-1411.mount
           681ms nvidia-persistenced.service
           678ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
           669ms dev-loop15.device
```

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. You may be able to get help on one of our sister sites such as [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Good point, thanks @MichaelHampton - I'll move this over to Ask Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hmm. Remove unwanted snaps (and possibly replace them with debs), or

`systemctl disable snapd.service` will solve your problems, permanently.

If you don't want to be that radical, you have to decide on how you would want your **desired** snaps to start: on demand, during boot or spread over some time after boot? Each of these approaches has it's own set of downsides that must be considered for particular use case.

Personally, I try to minimize amount of installed snaps to the bare minimum, and they don't bother me much.

Comment: I guess that's the core of my question - how do I change individual snaps so that they do not mount during boot?

Comment: If I want them to start on-demand, how do I do this?